# Is there a word “ribike” in Hungarian?

Tags: hungarian

I once read a Hungarian (I believe) fairytale about a girl named Ribike. You can find it here: http://multicoloreddiary.blogspot.com/2019/04/c-is-for-currant-girl-to-z-challenge.html?m=1
It’s said that the heroine’s name was derived from the word “currant”. So I used it as a nickname once and was told that “ribike” actually means something sex-related in Hungarian. Is it true? Is there a word “ribike” in Hungarian at all? I haven’t found anything in the dictionary, but it decided to check if it’s maybe some sort of slang.
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, *ribes* is the Latin word for currant, so it seems at least plausible.

Comment: And in Austrian German, currants are *Ribisel*, a loan from Latin or Italian.

Comment: Well, "ribizli" means "currant", "ribanc" means "slut", "ribi" is its slang. And "ribike" is something like "little slut". -ka/-ke works like the english -let or spanish -ito/-ita. (e.g. pig->piglet)

Comment: Too bad the question was closed, because I have the answer, as I remember having read that fairy-tale. It's the Hungarian translation of the character Rapunzel, and the Hungarian name comes from the berry "currant", and the variant I've read calls her "Ribizke". But you'll likely only find it in older translations of the original German fairytale, as the modern Disney version calls her "Aranyhaj" (golden hair) in its translation.

Comment: It means literally "little slut", but in a sort of loving way. "Ribizli" or "ribiszke" is currant, so it is connected to both words.

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia gives Magyar [**ribiszke**](https://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribiszke) for the members of the currant family *[Ribes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribes)*.

Comment: And this is the Hungarian name for the well-known fairy tale character called Rapunzel. (before Disney renamed her)